# Excel breaking lines where it shouldn't

Tags: excel

I have an excel File filled with data which often doesn't fit in one line. Obviously these lines are getting split into two. Working as intended so far. But sometimes Excel decides there is a need for a line break even tough the text *does* fit on one line.

[image]

My guess would be that Excel sets a margin for its cells, but how can I modify it to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

`WordWrap` a.k.a. `Wrap Text` is your friend:

[image]

[Here you can see more](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Wrap-text-in-a-cell-2a18cff5-ccc1-4bce-95e4-f0d4f3ff4e84).

Comment: WordWrap is already activated, considering I want lines to split automatically when it is too long. However, sometimes it splits even tough the content of a cell would fit on one line

Comment: Added a second picture to visualize it more

Answer (score 0):

If you are copy pasting.
Paste the desired object within the box with the blinking cursor (Easy).
This will paste the contents only within a block.
if the documents from which you are copying the content consists of line breaks for new paragraphs then excel takes those line breaks as new rows/columns.

for your problems if your document has made split cells for the content, Try
Selecting the columns you wish to combine together.
then use the formula.

=CONCAT(CELL A,CELL B)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've checked the data. There is no line break in there which could cause this

Comment: Usually The data in Excel displays as if it were split. Try to increase the width of the row/column

Comment: When I do so I get the same problem in other places of the file. Additionally, this document gets filled by software so it doesn't make sense for me to change this manually afterwards every time